# bind9 service fails to start citing permissions issues

Tags: server, 18.04, dns, services, bind

I'm getting a fatal `loading configuration: permission denied` error when trying to start the bind9 service.

```
root@dns:~# sudo service bind9 stop
root@dns:~# sudo service bind9 start
root@dns:~# sudo service bind9 status
● bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-08-17 23:58:55 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
  Process: 973 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1005 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1005 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: using 1 UDP listener per interface
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: using up to 4096 sockets
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: /etc/bind/named.conf.local:9: open: /var/freeday/sink_local.conf: permission denied
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: loading configuration: permission denied
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st named[1005]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st systemd[1]: bind9.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 23:58:55 dns.gho.st systemd[1]: bind9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However the permissions for `sink_local.conf` are identical to `named.conf.local`

```
root@dns:~# ls -alh /etc/bind/ | grep named.conf.local
-rw-r--r--  1 root bind  205 Aug 17 23:57 named.conf.local
root@dns:~# ls -alh /var/freeday/ | grep sink_local.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1020 Aug 17 22:56 sink_local.conf
root@dns:~# ls -alh /var | grep freeday
drwxr-xr-x  3 root bind   4.0K Aug 17 22:56 freeday
```

I'm running this on a new 18.04LTS Ubuntu image on Linode.

Has anyone had this issue before? And what should my next trouble shooting be?

Comment: And what is `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`, line `9`? Lines `1` to `$`?

Comment: Use my `pathlld` script, available from https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"